# how to get the position(Y - coordinate) of textview in linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

In my Linearlayout, multiple textviews are present. I need to find out the position(Y-cooridinate) of particular textview. Is it possible? If yes, then please provide some reference.

Any help or guidance to resolve the issue will be well appreciated.

Comment: Position based on what? You might use the method getPaddingTop and getPaddingBottom but i doubt it'll satisfy your requirements.

Comment: Hi Barışcan Kayaoğlu, thanks for the quick reply. Actually, I need to scroll to that particular textview on the click of button, which I have placed at the bottom of the screen(outside the linearlayout).

Comment: I see.. Well, there are easier methods like using list view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
float y = mTextView.getY();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Comment: Hi Morendo, thanks for the quick reply. In my case, value of getY() method is coming same for all textviews present in linearlayout.

Comment: Are your textview on a row or several rows and columns ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Y-coordinate of a `TextView` using

```
textView.getY();
```